# How to add discussion board in page automatically in Sharepoint 2010?

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, sharepoint-2010

We create a discussion board in Sharepoint 2010 without much effort, but I am looking for a solution where discussion board and all its replies are added to the certain zone automatically. That is end user do not need to add discussion board, through the process of entering page into edit mode and then adding web part. But instead, once user create a discussion board, all discussions and message are added to the page automatically (to certain zone in page).

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this code the a web event handler (ListAdded) in order to run this code automatically.  In that code you will need to check if the list type is of Discussion.  In the event receiver you will need get a reference to the SPWeb in which you want to add the web part, and to the list you want to use (in this example the Contacts list). Next you create an instance of the ListViewWebPart class, in which you can set the ZoneID, the ListName and the ViewGuid. This is the tricky part, the ListName property should contain the ID of your list (a GUID), not the name of your list!! But the ListName property is of the type string, so you need to convert the List GUID to a string using .ToString(“B”).ToUpper(). The same goes for the ViewGuid. Finally you need to get a reference to the WebPartCollection for the page in which you want to add the web part (in this example the home page, being default.aspx). Now you can add the web part using the Add method.

```
using Microsoft.SharePoint;
using Microsoft.SharePoint.WebPartPages;

// Get a reference to a web and a list
SPSite site = new SPSite("http://localhost:8000");
SPWeb web = site.OpenWeb();
SPList list = web.Lists["Contacts"];

// Instantiate the web part
ListViewWebPart wp = new ListViewWebPart();
wp.ZoneID = "Left";
wp.ListName = list.ID.ToString("B").ToUpper();
wp.ViewGuid = list.DefaultView.ID.ToString("B").ToUpper();

// Get the web part collection
SPWebPartCollection coll = 
    web.GetWebPartCollection("default.aspx", 
    Storage.Shared);

// Add the web part
coll.Add(wp);
```